# Does $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f(z^n)$ converges locally uniformly on unit disk

Tags: complex-analysis

If $f(z)$ is analytic in the unit disk and $f(0)=0$ , show that $$f(z)+f(z^2)+\cdots f(z^n)\cdots $$ converges locally uniformly to an analytic function in the unit disk.

I am thinking to apply Weierstrass M test to show the convergence is uniform. But not sure if this works or not.
Does anyone have idea?

Comment: Cauchy criterion

Comment: $|f(z^n)|\le M_R R^n$ for $|z|\le R$, with $|M_R|=\max_{|z|\le R} |f'(z)|$.

Answer (score 1):

Weierstrass M-test + Schwartz lemma give you the result.